# on-click event does not make the other field editable in one-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<!--Below is the html code-->

 <div ng-init="InitializeFields()">
    <input type="text" on-click="makeOtherReadOnly('1')" 
    readonly="show_or_not_first"/>
   <input type="text" on-click="makeOtherReadOnly('2')" readonly="show_or_not_second"/>
 </div>
```

// Now inside javascript

```
  $scope.makeOtherReadOnly=function(number){
  if(number==='1'){
  show_or_not_second=true;
 show_or_not_first=false;
  show_or_not_second=true;
 }else if(number==='2'){
show_or_not_first=true;
  show_or_not_second=false;
 }
 };

   $scope.Initializer=function(){
  show_or_not_first=false;
    show_or_not_second=false;
   }

   $scope.Initializer();
```

the problem that I am facing is as I click on the input field, it should turn the other field to readonly after pafe gets loaded and we have either field clicked, but it requires two click...

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: It should be `ng-click`, not on-click

Answer (score 1):

Try changing on-click to ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct few things ion your code :

1. change on-click to `ng-click`, So your function can be called from HTML.
2. Change `readonly` to `ng-readonly`, So you can utilize `$scope` property
3. In your `ng-init`, I guess you need to call `Initializer()` method to initialize default value.

Further just to make 2 input box `readonly`, you can chieve this by 1 flag. and no string comparison.

**Simple Demo :**

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.makeOtherReadOnly = function(boolValue) {
    console.log(boolValue);
    $scope.data.first = boolValue;
  };

  $scope.Initializer = function() {
    $scope.data = {
      first: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-init="Initializer()">

   First: <input type="text" ng-click="makeOtherReadOnly(false)" 
    ng-readonly="data.first" />

   Second: <input type="text" ng-click="makeOtherReadOnly(true)" 
    ng-readonly="!data.first" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two scopes here

javascript and angular 
sometimes inside ng-click, javqascript  function don't work

so change on-click to ng-click.

Comment: I also observed it. I would not advise to mix angular function with javascript functions.